# Convert decimals 1-10 to Roman Numeral; Vice versa via created class and methods

Tags: c#, string, char

New project!
Write a Roman Numeral class. Given an integer value between 1 and 10, the Roman Numeral class should be able to convert this decimal value to a Roman Numeral. The class should also contain a method that would convert a Roman Numeral to its decimal equivalent. Write a second class (console or form) to test your Roman Numeral class. The second class should allow the user to input test values of each type.

So, what I have in my class is this:

```
namespace RomanNumber
{
class RomanNumeral
{
    private int numToRoman;
    private string romNumber;
    private string romanToNum;


    public RomanNumeral()
    {
    }

    public RomanNumeral(int numNumber)
    {
        numToRoman = numNumber;
    }

    public int NumToRoman
    {
        get
        {
            return numToRoman;
        }
        set
        {
            numToRoman = value;
        }
    }

    public string RomanToNum
    {
        get
        {
            return romanToNum;
        }
        set
        {
            romanToNum = value;
        }
    }


    public string ReturnRomNum()
    {
        string romanNum;
        switch (romNumber)
        {
            case '1':
                romanNum = "I";
                break;
            case '2':
                romanNum = "II";
                break;
            case '3':
                romanNum = 'III';
                break;
            case '4':
                romanNum = 'IV';
                break;
            case '5':
                romanNum = 'V';
            case '6':
                romanNum = 'VI';
                break;
            case '7':
                romanNum = 'VII';
                break;
            case '8':
                romanNum = 'VIII';
                break;
            case '9':
                romanNum = 'IX';
                break;
            case '10':
                romanNum = 'X';
                break;
            default:
                romanNum = "Error";
                break;
        }
        return romanNum;
    }

    public int ReturnNomNum()
    {
        int numberNum;
        switch (romanToNum)
            case 'I':
            romanToNum = "1";
            break;
            case 'II':
            romanToNum = "2";
            break;
            case 'III':
            romanToNum = '3';
            break;
            case 'IV':
            romanToNum = '4';
            break;
            case 'V':
            romanToNum = '5';
            case 'VI':
            romanToNum = '6';
            break;
            case 'VII':
            romanToNum = '7';
            break;
            case 'VIII':
            romanToNum = '8';
            break;
            case 'IX':
            romanToNum = '9';
            break;
            case 'X':
            romanToNum = '10';
            break;
            default:
            romanToNum = "Error";
            break;
        }
        return romanToNum;


    }






}
}
```

I've seen other example of the RomanNumeral class all over, but they all look WAY more complicated than anything we've learned in class. Just wonder if I can take what I have and make it work once I create a test class. Please helP!! Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a `break` in `case 5` and `case 'V'`. Also, strings are delimited with double quote characters, "like this".

Comment: Thanks for your response! Didn't even noticed I left all of that out. Do you think what I did will work properly?

Comment: You can also simplify this by just returning in the cases, and removing the breaks. :)

Answer (score 1):

This smells like homework. I'll lend a hand and get you half way there with an int to roman method.

```
private string ToRoman(int input)
{
    var lookup = new Dictionary<string, int> { {"M", 1000}, {"CM", 900}, {"D", 500}, {"CD", 400}, {"C", 100},
        {"XC", 90}, {"L", 50}, {"XL", 40}, {"X", 10}, {"IX", 9}, {"V", 5}, {"IV", 4}, {"I", 1} };
    var output = string.Empty;
    var remainder = input;
    foreach (var digit in lookup.Keys)
    {
        while (remainder >= lookup[digit])
        {
            output += digit;
            remainder -= lookup[digit];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This is a homework assignment. I've seen this online. As stated, I'm only doing integers from 1 to 10. Could I take all of the bigger numerals out of that method's code and it still work? Again, this from what my professor shouldn't be this complex. I could be wrong. Not sure.

Comment: Yes, you could take out references to LCDM and it would still work. It just wouldn't return correct results for numbers 40 and over. Even with them in  it won't give good results over 4000 since the roman number system wasn't made with larger numbers in mind.